# How can I check if a file has been modified with jquery

Tags: javascript, live, jquery

I'm trying to figure out how I can have an "automatic updating system" with like jquery or something. How could I do this?

Comment: Please clarify. What sort of file? Where is the file? What do you mean by "updating"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set up a mechanism to check for updates via AJAX (via a timer or something like that), you could do what your looking for using this [publish/subscribe plugin](http://www.novasoftware.com/download/jquery/Publish-subscribe.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

jQuery can not tell if a local file has been updated.

However, you could request a file if it respects [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), store its contents, and then request it again later. Then just do a comparison of the new contents vs the old contents.